# DynamoDB ADD Transaction Fails Intermittently for no Apparent Reason

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am having an intermittent problem with DynamoDB with a writing a bunch of entries. I cannot see what the problem and the weird thing the problem occurs in a place where there is no `ConditionExpression`. This exception happens about 1 in 10 times.

`docClient.transactWrite(transaction).promise()` with:

```
{
    "TransactItems": [
        {
            "Update": {
                "TableName": "protect-dev-stepfunction-ScanAggregation",
                "Key": {
                    "pk": "#ScanCount#",
                    "sort": "#Total"
                },
                "UpdateExpression": "ADD queued :queued, runningFiles :runningFiles",
                "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                    ":queued": 1,
                    ":runningFiles": 0
                },
                "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
            }
        },
        {
            "Update": {
                "TableName": "protect-dev-stepfunction-ScanAggregation",
                "Key": {
                    "pk": "#ScanCount#",
                    "sort": "#Tenant#pwc"
                },
                "UpdateExpression": "SET isTenant = :isTenant ADD queued :queued, runningFiles :runningFiles",
                "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                    ":queued": 1,
                    ":runningFiles": 0,
                    ":isTenant": true
                },
                "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
            }
        },
        {
            "Put": {
                "TableName": "protect-dev-stepfunction-Jobs",
                "Item": {
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-11 05:25:58.770369",
                    "scanId": "1161",
                    "tenantId": "pwc",
                    "TaskToken": "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",
                    "priority": "3",
                    "fileId": "3179",
                    "pk": "pwc",
                    "sort": "3-1161_3179",
                    "scanStatus": "SUBMITTED",
                    "rjk": "3-1161_3179"
                },
                "ConditionExpression": "attribute_not_exists(pk) and attribute_not_exists(sort)"
            }
        }
    ]
}{
    "TransactItems": [
        {
            "Update": {
                "TableName": "protect-dev-stepfunction-ScanAggregation",
                "Key": {
                    "pk": "#ScanCount#",
                    "sort": "#Total"
                },
                "UpdateExpression": "ADD queued :queued, runningFiles :runningFiles",
                "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                    ":queued": 1,
                    ":runningFiles": 0
                },
                "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
            }
        },
        {
            "Update": {
                "TableName": "protect-dev-stepfunction-ScanAggregation",
                "Key": {
                    "pk": "#ScanCount#",
                    "sort": "#Tenant#pwc"
                },
                "UpdateExpression": "SET isTenant = :isTenant ADD queued :queued, runningFiles :runningFiles",
                "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                    ":queued": 1,
                    ":runningFiles": 0,
                    ":isTenant": true
                },
                "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
            }
        },
        {
            "Put": {
                "TableName": "protect-dev-stepfunction-Jobs",
                "Item": {
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-11 05:25:58.770369",
                    "scanId": "1161",
                    "tenantId": "pwc",
                    "TaskToken": "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",
                    "priority": "3",
                    "fileId": "3179",
                    "pk": "pwc",
                    "sort": "3-1161_3179",
                    "scanStatus": "SUBMITTED",
                    "rjk": "3-1161_3179"
                },
                "ConditionExpression": "attribute_not_exists(pk) and attribute_not_exists(sort)"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I get this stacktrace:

```
TransactionCanceledException: Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [TransactionConflict, TransactionConflict, None]
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message:
   'Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [TransactionConflict, TransactionConflict, None]',
  code: 'TransactionCanceledException',
  time: 2020-05-11T05:26:00.972Z,
  requestId: 'ABKB5RCR30SDASOL3KGS5KEBUJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 32.29530018146246 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it's a "TransactionConflict", which [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-conflict-handling) says can happen in these scenarios:

> - A `PutItem`, `UpdateItem`, or `DeleteItem` request for an item conflicts with an ongoing `TransactWriteItems` request that includes the same item.
> - An item within a `TransactWriteItems` request is part of another ongoing `TransactWriteItems` request.
> - An item within a `TransactGetItems` request is part of an ongoing `TransactWriteItems`, `BatchWriteItem`, `PutItem`, `UpdateItem`, or `DeleteItem` request.

In your case, it looks like the 2nd scenario.  How much concurrency is there on your records?

Comment: This was correct there was more than one process accessing the same record.

Comment: @AnthonyKong Yes that would be the most straightforward workaround.  If the error happens too often, you could try to mitigate it by changing your data model and access patterns so there is less concurrency on the affected items, but how you achieve that depends very much on your use case.  Or, if possible, you may want to avoid transactions because concurrent normal requests like `UpdateItem` don't cause these `TransactionConflict` errors between them.  (`UpdateItem` is particularly nice because it can read AND modify an item in a single, atomic operation which is great for concurrency.)